# I cant move any elements in the layout (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I cant move any elements in the layout (android studio) for some reason..
I searched alot and nothing worked with me.
All text views or buttons (all elements) stays top-left and I cant move them or even resize them...
Whats the solution for that?
And if I tried to resize the button it fills up the whole screen.

[thats the code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sooU.png)

Comment: Can you switch to the Code view of your layout and post it?

Comment: ok check the post

Comment: Post the code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you have used constraint layout in your XML file.
and the constraints as you have given in your file that makes your elements stay up at the top left.

Solution 1:
When you give start to start constraint to the parent and end to end constraint to the parent it makes your view to stick to the both side of the screen.

Even if you have given your view's height and width to wrap content it will be considered as match parent.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>
             <Button android:id="@+id/button" ...
                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
         </>
```

as This will make your view to stretch to the both side of the screen and will take whole space horizontally.

[image: Stretched view]

all you need to do is remove the constraints mentioned below:

**if you want to let your view to stick to the left side of the screen-**

> Remove EndtoEndof = parent constraint

**if you want to let your view to stick to the right side of the screen-**

> Remove StarttoStartof = parent constraint

The issue with resizing the button is that you have given the constraints to the view to stick to bottom and top of the screen so it will take up whole screen vertically.

**if you want to make your button to stay to the bottom**

> Remove toptotopof = parent

**if you want to make your button to stay to the top**

> Remove bottomtoBottomof= parent

all you need is to understand how constraint layout works .

Look into [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#:%7E:text=A%20ConstraintLayout%20is%20a%20ViewGroup,API%20and%20capabilities%20over%20time.) it will help you understand the constraint layout from broad perspective.